# POST Complex objects to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working on an enterprise scale  project where I have a self referencing table called categories as below. Also in my current model I am using following table associations to fetch data. ( using EF6).

[image]

I have M-M mapping tables in DB for above M-M relationships.

In my controller GET action result returns the model which has Ilist(all parent categories). Then when the user is selecting items (in view) I am using Ajax to retrieve Ilist for next subset of categories (by passing to controller by Id - return Json result) and dynamically show next to the parent select list as below. ( and I have up to 4 subsets)

[image]

As the user is selecting categories, I am using Ajax call to load related categories and create selectlist or dropdownlist  dynamically as below:

[image]

My question is Since all these data is loaded through Ajax, how can I bind them to my parent model. How can I capture user selected data into one parent model when user is posting the from to controller.

I know I can use Ajax and use Json to capture & transfer to contoller , But I need to use modelview , Can I use partiview to overcome this ?

Please advise the available options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is making sure the name values match the object hierarchy accepted by the post operation.  This is certainly doable; it's difficult because several AJAX operations build the UI, but one operation processes it, so you have to ensure the data expressions match the object being posted back.

You can use Html.NameFor() as a workaround to ensuring the naming paths work OK.  Collections can make this difficult.